# Recommendations on .NET OCR engine

Tags: .net, ocr

My company has tasked me with finding an OCR engine that fits our development needs.  A quick google search has a number of this listed out, but we do not have the time required to vet all of these and were hoping to narrow it down. Free or purchasable licenses are ok either way.

Currently we have investigated:
Tesseract - it is open source, which is great - however our team overall is new to OCR technology and we worry that community forums will not be sufficient for guidance Adobe OCR - this worked ok in tests but the supported languages are extremely limited

Currently we are only looking to implement English and a few select European languages but would like to have the option in the future to expand if the application does well.

Our application is a .net web api, written in .NET 5

Any suggestions or recommendations from personal experiences working with OCR engines would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a library that supports multiple languages, you can check out the company I work for as we have a free evaluation of our commercial OCR Engine
OCR can be performed on an image with only a few lines of code:

OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD);
ocrEngine.Startup(null, null, null, null);
ocrEngine.AutoRecognizeManager.Run(inputFile, outputFile,  DocumentFormat.PDF, null);

The libraries can be obtained in a .net 5 web api via the Leadtools.Ocr nuget package here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Ocr/

More information on the languages supported can be found here: https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/to/ocr-languages-and-spell-checking.html